# How to change the colors of a website in real time?

Tags: javascript, css, drupal

I am designing a theme and have a provision to change the color of various elements. There will not be a preview of any sort. But I came across [this demo](http://themeforest.net/item/creative-the-premium-portfolio-theme/full_screen_preview/240470) where you can change the colors of certain elements of a site in real time(using the pallete on the left side)
I know we can use JS to change the css in real time. But how can I implement a similar thing from the above link?

Thanks

Comment: Google "style switcher".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like, you're looking for a plugin, do you?

Maybe, this fits your needs.

http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

It provides various callbacks you can interact with. They even do have some examples on their site.

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    }
});
```

jQuery is needed.